# Using "since" in interrogative sentences

Tags: conjunctions

I am confused about the usage of these conjunctions. Please help. My answer is 2/1, but I am not so sure.

(1) Why did you buy these books ___ you hardly read?

1. since
2. when
3. because
4. as

(2) ___ you hardly read, why did you buy these books?

1. since
2. when
3. because
4. as

Comment: (1): 'When' is incontestably correct in (1); the absolute need for a comma before 'as' in that sentence is arguable nowadays. //  (2): It's also arguable whether 'since' having the 'given that' sense that 'as' has is idiomatic in this sentence, and hence whether 'since' is acceptable along with 'as' in (2). 'When' would be unusual in a leading subordinate clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm leaning towards *when* for both.

*Since* and *because* convey the same meaning, which doesn't really fit here:

> **since, because**:  for the reason that

*As* would also take on the same meaning in the given context.

> **when**: in view of the fact that; considering that.

So, *when* seems to fit in perfectly.

> Why did you buy these books *when* you hardly read?
>
> *When* you hardly read, why did you buy these books?

However, *as* can also mean 'although' in certain cases, but I'd have to say it in this way to use it:

> *Bibliophobic as you are*, why did you buy these books?

.. for lack of a better adjective :P

Comment: Collins licenses the 'given that' sense for both 'as' and 'since'. And I'm not happy that 'When you hardly read, why did you buy these books?' sounds as natural as the other ordering. It's very formal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're right, it does sound more formal, but I think that's just the consequence of reordering the sentence. As for 'as', I can't be sure.